# Adjust DataGridView's columns to fill available space if the grid is smaller and use scroll in case the grid bigger than the space available

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I want to adjust all columns of a DataGridView according to the required space to show all its data completely. If the space required is smaller than the available space i want the grid to fill this exceeding space, but if the available is space is not enough to display properly all columns i want to DataGridView create automatically a scroll. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 13):

Click over the DataGridView and select "Edit Columns...", then go to "Layout" and set "AutoSizeMode" to "Fill".

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep your table (DataGridView) formatted such that all of the columns are automatically sized, but one column in particular fills the remaining space, you can do something like this:

```
//Store the number of columns in a variable
int columnCount = dataGridView.Columns.Count;

//If we want the last column to fill the remaining space
int lastColumnIndex = columnCount - 1;

//Loop through each column and set the DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode
//In this case, if we will set the size of all columns automatically, but have
//the last column fill any extra space available.
foreach(DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView.Columns) 
{
    if (column.Index == columnCount - lastColumnIndex) //Last column will fill extra space
    {
        column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    }
    else //Any other column will be sized based on the max content size
    {
        column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    }
}

//Turn the scrollbars on for the DataGridView if needed
dataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
```

Comment: While this works for the scenario you presented in the opening of the answer, it doesn't answer the OP's question, which is how to auto-size the columns to display all their data and then create a scrollbar (I think) if applicable

Comment: @Taegost Setting the auto-size mode on all of the columns to AllCells makes all of the columns automatically resize to fit the data in their respective cells. Making the last column fill the remaining space does as the OP desires. I've edited my original answer to set the ScrollBars property on the DataGridView. Setting the Scrollbars property to ScrollBars.Both should  force the scrollbars to show up if the table is too big to be displayed.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  SOrry, I had a brain fart when I posted that comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to DataGridView Property select "AutoSizeColumnsMode". Set "Fill".

Answer (score 1):

DataGridView properties -> "AutoSizeMode" to "Fill" does fill up all the available space, however if a column is large enough to occupy majority of grid space, then rest of the columns size would shrink.

May be you can try "AutoSizeMode" to "AllCells". This not only fills up entire grid but also makes enough space to view all columns(with horizontal scroll bar)

Answer (score 1):

For adjusting column size when the number of columns in Datagridview are dynamic, need to find the width of the columns getting displayed in Datagrid.
In designer set Autosize to DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None

```
    Dim dgvBOMcolumnWidth As Integer = 0
    For Each gridcol As DataGridViewColumn In DgvBOMHeader.Columns
        If (gridcol.Visible) Then
            dgvBOMcolumnWidth = gridcol.Width + dgvBOMcolumnWidth
        End If
    Next

    If (dgvBOMcolumnWidth < DgvBOMHeader.Width) Then //if dynamic column width is less than actual grid width ,fill the columns.
        For Each gridcol As DataGridViewColumn In DgvBOMHeader.Columns
            gridcol.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
        Next
    Else
        DgvBOMHeader.AutoSize = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None
    End If
```