# DataGridView Fill Columns Exactly

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

We have a data grid which has 6 columns. We need to make sure that the 6 columns are filled completely in the datagridview.

We tried `dataView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);`. It did not work. 
What should we do ?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024967/adjust-datagridviews-columns-to-fill-available-space-if-the-grid-is-smaller-and?rq=1

Comment: Can you show us your aspx code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try something like this, it pans out the columns to fill the datagrid;

```
DataGrid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

or

```
DataGrid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

Lemme know if this isn't what you're looking for and i'll change it. There are other possible options for DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode, just have a look through the intelisense if you want to try the others.

Answer (score 0):

You can set AutoSizeMode property of one of the columns to be Fill. This will cause the column to always resize itself to fill all the available space.

This link can help:

[Adjust DataGridView's columns to fill available space if the grid is smaller and use scroll in case the grid bigger than the space available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024967/adjust-datagridviews-columns-to-fill-available-space-if-the-grid-is-smaller-and?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`AutoSizeColumnsMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizecolumnsmode.aspx) property value to `Fill`.

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```