# Stretching dataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want my dataGridView collumns to stretch when I change window size, I added anchor properties to grid view, but it only resizes background, not collumns, how can I do this?
My problem looks like:
[image: small window]

[image: big window]

Comment: Set the width on all your columns to "*"

Comment: Where can I do this? When I try to set width to `*` in code or in properties window it shows me error.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I see you are using datagridview which is a winform control. Is this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024967/adjust-datagridviews-columns-to-fill-available-space-if-the-grid-is-smaller-and

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set AutoSizeColumnsMode to Fill :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See here:  [MSDN on DataGridViewColumn.AutoSizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.autosizemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
and here: 
[MSDN on AutoSizeColumnMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Maybe** this is what you want :

> All fill-mode columns in the control divide the available space in
>   proportions determined by their **FillWeight** property values.

But **finding out what you want** is not as easy as most people think. Your images show a change not only in size bur also in font size. Is that really what you want?? I hope not, as this would surprise the user who is used to get more data on the windows when making it larger and won't expect to see larger fonts..

To get there set the properties of all columns you want to participate is the resize.

Comment: font is still the same on pictures, I only resized pictures, because I didnt want effect like:
[==] [=====], so I resized both images to [==]

Comment: Ah, yes, now I see it, too, sorry!  Do have a look at the `FillWeight` property of each column  or else e.g. the ID column will stretch as well..!