# Formatting a datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, formatting

Hi everyone i just wanted to ask how can i make the appearance of my datagridview better

I just wanted to remove the spaces enclosed in the red lines ,are there any way that I can extend my database to the full sisze of my datagridview?

[image]

Thank in advance

Comment: What platform: Winforms, WPF, etc...? WPF would be a better choice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024967/adjust-datagridviews-columns-to-fill-available-space-if-the-grid-is-smaller-and

Comment: @OneFineDay: This is almost certainly WinForms. WPF doesn't have any control named `DataGridView`.

Comment: You can set those properties in the Datagridview itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `AutoSizeMode` to `fill` for `Name` column

Answer (score 0):

Your question has nothing to do with the database.  You can fiddle with the auto-sizing of the columns so that they occupy the full width of the grid.  To fill the space at the bottom you would have to change the height of the rows, which would be unusual and is not something that would happen automatically.  You could just change the grid background colour to white so it looks less like empty space.